# Error while running spark with oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I am running a spark streaming application inside oozie. It runs good in dev environment where the spark version is 1.3.0. But in other region it fails with below error.

```
2016-04-27 05:39:58,142 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ContainerId: container_e31_1461603486630_0010_01_000001
```

This region has 1.5 version of spark. The CDH version is 5.5.0. I understand it is something to do with the spark version but the oozie share lib's spark-core jar version is also 1.5 and the spark assembly also has 1.5 version. Below is my workflow.xml and properties file. I also tried adding the classpath directly in workflow.xml but that doesn't help either.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" name="sample" >
<start to="spark-stream" />
    <action name="spark-stream">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${job_tracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${name_node}</name-node>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>jobname</name>
            <class>classname</class>
            <jar>/path/jar</jar>
            <spark-opts>--executor-cores 100 --executor-memory  12G --driver-memory 4G --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.8/lib/hadoop/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.8/lib/hadoop/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar</spark-opts>

        </spark>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="mail_users"/>
    </action>

        <action name="mail_users">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
            <to>sample@sample.com</to>

            <subject>Job failed</subject>
            <body>Please check</body>
        </email>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="end"/>
    </action>
    <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

Properties file:

```
job_tracker=server:8032
name_node=hdfs://server:8020
examplesRoot=rootdir
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${name_node}/test/${examplesRoot}
```

My lib folder has spark assembly jar as well as the job jar. Could someone suggest a workaround or solution for this.

Comment: check that your spark assembly built with the same version of Hadoop as your YARN cluster

Comment: This is the spark assembly jar. spark-assembly-1.5.0-cdh5.5.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar. It says version 2.6.0 and spark as 1.5.0 which is my cluster's version as well.

Comment: Btw, why you need spark assembly in your  app directory? Oozie on Cloudera has spark libs in sharelib. I guess it worse trying to run your workflow without your spark-assembly instance in classpath

Comment: I removed the spark assembly jar from lib. It still shows the same error. One difference with dev and this environment is that oozie lib was not there so I installed it from cloudera manager.

Comment: what version of Spark specified in your application build definition (pom.xml, build.sbt, etc)? is it compile or provided dependency?

Comment: build.sbt has 1.5 version of spark

Comment: I guess you have to specify in your build definition exact version of Spark that matches your Cloudera Spark instance. Your can get it in Cloudera maven [repository](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html).  You can even make it provided

Comment: I tried updating all spark and hadoop versions as per my CDH version.. no luck.. still same issue

Comment: Ok. Last chance: try to re-deploy your oozie sharelib with Cloudera's default version of Spark.

Comment: No luck. Downloaded oozie shae lib again and restarted oozie and tried. Still same issue.